# Got error code(5) access denied when use TerminateProcess to terminate the "mstsc.exe" process

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I use the `CreateProcess()` function to launch the rdp client app using "mstsc.exe". After that, I want to terminate it so I use `TerminateProcess()` function, but it fails with error code of 5. If I replace the "mstsc.exe" with "notepad.exe", the terminate function works. The code are as follows:

```
TCHAR szCommandLine[] = TEXT("mstsc.exe");
STARTUPINFO si = {sizeof(si)};
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
BOOL bResult = CreateProcess(NULL, szCommandLine, NULL, NULL,
    FALSE, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
::Sleep(3000);
if (TerminateProcess(pi.hProcess, 0) == 0) {
printf("failed: %d", GetLastError());
}
```

Can anyone help explain it and solve it?
What I observed is that the pid of the `pi` returned is different from the id of the process "mstsc.exe" observed in taksmanager or "Process Explorer".

Comment: Error 5 is `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your host process 32-bit and you are running on 64-bit windows?

If so, you are invoking the 32-bit mstsc and it is spawning a 64-bit version, hence the different PID.  Check out [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/22c10140-a502-4aa1-98d3-3607b8b573e8/)

Comment: Thank you, it makes sense. I run win32 app in Win7 64bit.

Comment: I added the following code before run mstsc.exe and use the 32 version of mstsc.exe under "c:\windows\system32" then it can be terminated:  PVOID OldValue = NULL;
BOOL result = Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(&OldValue);

Answer (score 3):

You must gain the privilege before terminating another process.

Try this:

```
void UpdatePrivilege(void)
{
    HANDLE hToken;
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp;
    LUID luid;

    if(OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY,&hToken))
    {
       LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL,SE_DEBUG_NAME, &luid);

       tp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
       tp.Privileges[0].Luid = luid;
       tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED; 

       AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &tp, sizeof(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES), NULL, NULL);
    }
}
```

Call this function before calling TerminateProcess.

Comment: That's not usually necessary when terminating a process running in the same context as yourself.  You should also note that it needs to be done before the call to OpenProcess, it won't work if you do it after the call to OpenProcess and before the call to TerminateProcess.

Comment: Sorry, Rango. I call the function you gave either before create process or before terminate process, but it remains the same.